# ChromeOS flex lenovo Ideapad 5

Tags: lenovo-laptop, google-chrome-os-flex

When I used Windows 11, my laptop's screen would automatically rotate when I flipped it, and the on-screen keyboard only appeared when I touched the screen, not when using the mouse to select somewhere to type. After switching to ChromeOS Flex, these features are not present in desktop mode. Is there a way to enable screen rotation and on-screen keyboard behavior like in Windows 11 without switching to Tablet mode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.